# bootsect.exe /nt60 - No bootcode was successfully updated

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, iso-image, cmd.exe

I am trying to modify my 500GB usb harddrive so I can use it to mimic a DVD BOOT disk

I have formatted and created a primary partition on it using
**cmd.exe**

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk G
clean
create partition primary size=10000
active
format fs=fat32 quick
assign
exit
```

- **H:** = Mounted ISO
- **G:** = USB Harddrive

I run cmd as administrator in a new cmd and run the following cmds.

```
H:
cd boot
bootsect.exe /nt60 G:
```

which returns the error

```
Target volumes will be updated with BOOTMGR compatible bootcode.

G: (\\?\Volume{3jkrkmr-dsfd-22s2r4fd-defdgfdgfdgfdg})

    FAT32 filesystem bootcode is only supported on hardware with 512 byte
    sector sizes.

No bootcode was successfully updated.
```

I have tried to run cmd as normal(without administrator)

The error returns

```
Target volumes will be updated with BOOTMGR compatible bootcode.

Could not map drive partitions to the associated volume device objects:
    Access is denied.
```

Answer (score 2):

Reading your second error message carefully, note you got

`FAT32 filesystem bootcode is only supported on hardware with 512 byte
sector sizes.`

It's a a roundabout way of telling you that the defaults on `diskpart` were no good. You'd need to go back into diskpart and do this over again, but this time, in your `format` command, instead of `quick`, specify `UNIT=512`. This will override the default allocation unit size and should allow the rest of the process to work.

Answer (score 2):

**The error:**
*Could not map drive partitions to the associated volume device objects:  "Access is denied"*
.. occurs if you didn't run command prompt as Administrator

Comment: To start cmd.exe as administrator: right click on `c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` and click "Run as administrator".

Answer (score 1):

Just came across this issue and whatever the OP's reason for this there is a new reason this can happen in later versions of windows 10 depending on the AV settings, windows defender can be blocking this.

One way to resolve: 
Go to Settings -> Virus & Threat Protection -> Protection History and you might see 'Protected memory access blocked' which you can 'allow' for this one instance and then retry the command.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off **Controlled folder access** under **Ransomware protection**, copy, then turn it back on.

[image]